# Condensing repetitive code within an "If Statement"

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, but after each condition for the "if" statement, the code is pretty much the same, except the first line. I was wondering if there was a way to reduce the code so that the code only runs through it only once.

```
For Each cel In AddOrRemoveRng
On Error Resume Next

If cel = "Add" And Not IsEmpty(cel.Offset(0, 1)) And Not cel.Offset(0, 3) = "0" Then
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_A).Value = "Add"
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_B).Value = cel.Offset(0, 3) 
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_C).Value = cel.Offset(0, 4) 
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_C).Value = cel.Offset(0, 5) 

    Asset_Row = Asset_Row + 1

ElseIf cel = "Remove" And Not cel.Offset(0, 3) = "0" Then
    TelecomAssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_A).Value = "Retire"
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_B).Value = cel.Offset(0, 3) 
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_C).Value = cel.Offset(0, 4) 
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_C).Value = cel.Offset(0, 5)
    
    Asset_Row = Asset_Row + 1

ElseIf cel = "Update" Then
    TelecomAssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_A).Value = "Update"
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_B).Value = cel.Offset(0, 3) 
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_C).Value = cel.Offset(0, 4) 
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_C).Value = cel.Offset(0, 5)
    
    Asset_Row = Asset_Row + 1


End If


Next cel
```

Comment: This writes two different values into `Cells(Asset_Row, Column_C)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Shortening Repetitive Code

- Note that the `add` case uses `AssetList`, while the other two cases use `TelecomAssetList`.
- I have replaced `AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_C).Value = cel.Offset(0, 5).Value` with `AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_D).Value = cel.Offset(0, 5).Value` (`_D` instead of `_C`): it makes no sense to write twice to the same cell.
- You can't use `On Error Resume Next` so 'loosely' and expect the code to work correctly. The statement is usually applied on a line or two with an appropriate 'closing follow-up',
  e.g. `On Error Goto 0`.
- By using the `DoWrite` boolean, you are controlling if the 4 repetitive lines will be executed.
- By using `LCase` and writing the cases in lower case, you are allowing lower/upper case typos, e.g. `Add`, `adD` and `add` are considered equal.
- By using `CStr`, besides its main purpose, possible error values will not raise an error.

```vb
Dim DoWrite As Boolean

For Each cel In AddOrRemoveRng.Cells

    Select Case LCase(CStr(cel.Value))
    Case "add"
        If Not IsEmpty(cel.Offset(0, 1)) Then
            If CStr(cel.Offset(0, 3).Value) <> "0" Then
                AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_A).Value = "Add"
                DoWrite = True
            End If
        End If
    Case "remove"
        If CStr(cel.Offset(0, 3).Value) <> "0" Then
            TelecomAssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_A).Value = "Retire"
            DoWrite = True
        End If
    Case "update"
        TelecomAssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_A).Value = "Update"
        DoWrite = True
    End Select
    
    If DoWrite Then
        DoWrite = False
        AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_B).Value = cel.Offset(0, 3).Value
        AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_C).Value = cel.Offset(0, 4).Value
        AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_D).Value = cel.Offset(0, 5).Value
        Asset_Row = Asset_Row + 1
    End If

Next cel
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this should help:

```
For Each cel In AddOrRemoveRng
On Error Resume Next

If cel = "Add" And Not IsEmpty(cel.Offset(0, 1)) And Not cel.Offset(0, 3) = "0" Then
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_A).Value = "Add"


ElseIf cel = "Remove" And Not cel.Offset(0, 3) = "0" Then
    TelecomAssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_A).Value = "Retire"
    

ElseIf cel = "Update" Then
    TelecomAssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_A).Value = "Update"


End If

    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_B).Value = cel.Offset(0, 3) 
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_C).Value = cel.Offset(0, 4) 
    AssetList.Cells(Asset_Row, Column_C).Value = cel.Offset(0, 5)

    Asset_Row = Asset_Row + 1

Next cel
```

Comment: That doesn't account for the case where `cel` is none of the specified values